# Unrecognized database format selecting RecordSource

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I'm updating a 2006 program written in VB6.  It has a large database created with Access 1997 with which the program works fine, but Access 2007 would not allow me to modify the database unless I converted it from .mdb to .accdb.

I did so and in Design mode, changed the DatabaseName to the .accdb extension, left RecordsetType as Dynaset, but when I click on RecordSource, I get an "unrecognized database format" message.

I've researched everything I could find on the web. Someone said to switch from *DAO* to *MS Office Access database engine* (12.0) which I did. Someone else suggested using Access (2007) to compact and repair it, which I did.

In Resources, I see *MS ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 library and *MS Data Environment Instance 1.0 (SP4)*.  I don't know what they are for offhand, not having looked at this software in a dozen+ years.

If I run it without specifying a RecordSource in Properties, when it gets to the line:
*Set rs_BidTable = db_BidBase.OpenRecordset("Table1")* (where Table1 is a table in the database) 
it gives a "Type mismatch" error message. None of the code changed after the update other than changing the database name in the code.

I could give more detail about what I have in the code, but since it's bombing in Design mode, I'm don't think the code is relevant (is it?).

I have other programs with databases updated to Access 2007 and never had this kind of problem.

Comment: Changing the extension will not "convert" the database. See [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/convert-a-database-to-the-accdb-file-format-098ddd31-5f84-4e89-8f44-db0cf7c11acd) support documentation on how to convert the Access database and the differences between those two formats.

Comment: I understand. When Access 2007 said it needed to update the database from 1997 in order to be able to modify the design, I told it to go ahead.  That is where my problems started.

Comment: Does it allow you to open the database using the shift key by-pass?

Comment: I found a video on YouTube about how to use VB6 with an ACCDB database, so I followed its directions to create a simple test project to use my existing ACCDB file and it worked - sort of. I followed the same 25 or so steps to get my database file to work with my old program and it too worked - sort of. The only problem now is that it will not accept the Query which I used as a data source to combine tables into one grid. The same query works with the MDB file. I won't hijack my own post to go into details on that here, but if I can't get it working, I'll make a new post.

Comment: I guess my original appeal for help has been solved. I don't know if I'm supposed to mark it as such or just go on my way. I could post the solution, but it's pretty lengthy. I don't know the protocol here. I should add that the same query works in the VB6 Data View window.